# How can I instantly update my selector dropdown value in jquery?

Tags: javascript

I write the following code;

```
var region = $('#inputGroupSelect01').val()
region = $('#inputGroupSelect01').change(function() {
  $(this).val()
})
console.log(region)
```

The console shows `k.fn.init(1)`. But I want `$(this).val()` will update the vaule of region variable. How can I set `$(this).val()` to region on change event?

#### Edit 1

I want this `region` variable in hazard section. like this way;

```
var hazardLayer = L.tileLayer.wms("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/tajikistan/wms", {
    layers: `tajikistan:${region}`,
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    version: '1.1.0',
    attribution: "country layer"
  });
```

I want the `hazardLayer`also in global scope. I can't put it inside the `change` event.

#### Edit 2

The `hazardLayer` will used in click function like this way;

```
$('#load').click(function () {
  hazardLayer.addTo(map);
});

$('#clear').click(function () {
  map.removeLayer(hazardLayer);
})
```

I have more than 10 layers like `hazardLayer` and seven variables like `region`. I need clean code so I want both in global scope.

Comment: Try assign `region` inside the function `$('#inputGroupSelect01').change(function() {
  region = $(this).val();
}) `

Comment: Actually I need the `region` variable in global scope.

Comment: Try doing a ```return```.  ```region = $('#inputGroupSelect01').change(function() { return $(this).val(); })```

Comment: `region` is available in global scope - Gets latest value from drop down change event

Comment: When will this hazardLayer be used?

Comment: I again updated my question. Please check out

Comment: My answer updated please check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like you said you you can define region variable to be in a global context, and decrease your lines of code/complexity by defining a function that returns a layer based on a passed layer.

```js
var region
var currentLayer

var region = $('#inputGroupSelect01').val()
region = $('#inputGroupSelect01').change(function () {
    $(this).val()
});

function createLayer(region) {
    return L.tileLayer.wms("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/tajikistan/wms", {
        layers: `tajikistan:${region}`,
        format: 'image/png',
        transparent: true,
        version: '1.1.0',
        attribution: "country layer"
    });
}

$('#load').click(function () {
    currentLayer = createLayer(region)
    currentLayer.addTo(map);
});

$('#clear').click(function () {
    map.removeLayer(currentLayer);
});
```

Comment: Thank. That is the exact answer what I want

Answer (score 2):

I know answer is already given in the comments but
to show the effective proof the answer.

Have a look at the below code,
As said in question's comments section by @user2932057,

region will be available global,

To check if the `region` value is updated or not,
You can just click the button to see the resultant value of `region`

```js
var region = $('#inputGroupSelect01').val();

var options = {
layers: `tajikistan:${region}`,
format: 'image/png',
transparent: true,
version: '1.1.0',
attribution: "country layer"
  };
var hazardLayer = L.tileLayer.wms("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/tajikistan/wms", options);

$('#inputGroupSelect01').change(function() {
  region = $(this).val();
  options.layers = `tajikistan:${region}`;
  console.log(region);
});
console.log(region);

$('#load').click(function () {
    hazardLayer = L.tileLayer.wms("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/tajikistan/wms", options);
    hazardLayer.addTo(map);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="inputGroupSelect01">
<option value="option1">option1</option>
<option value="option2">option2</option>
<option value="option3">option3</option>
<option value="option4">option4</option>
</select>

<button id="load">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: I want the changed value to instantly use in my `url` variable. suppose I have `url` variable that holds: `var url = 'http://example.com/'+region` region this way. How can I manage this?

Comment: take a variable like this `var url = 'http://example.com/'` outside onchange then inside onchange, assign `url += $(this).val;`

Comment: I edited my question. Could you please give me a suggestion?

Comment: at-least accept his answer ! if your problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to keep global variable for it. Just get value when you need.

```
console.log(getRegion())

function getRegion() {
    return $('#inputGroupSelect01').val()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#inputGroupSelect01').on('change',function(){
   var region =  $(this).val();
   console.log(region);
})
```